Movie or TV show where a gymnast beats her ex at paintball then stalks her undercover father in a yellow VW Beetle
It starts out with her ditching her date. He is later seen outside her house ; to avoid him she climbs into her house through the window, he spots her ( she is a gymnast), I think she rejects him. He is persistent.
Later when they're in a paintball match/competition she shoots him multiple times while she comes out unscathed despite wearing no protective gear (she is apparently an expert).
She owns a yellow beetle, lives with her mother (I think).. something comes up regarding her father in a conversation with her mother, she becomes determined to find out who he is...
She is following a man (her father) around in her yellow beetle. She is outside a restaurant where he is doing a job (espionage or assassination)... She either foils or is seen following her.
Later she is caught by her father (he doesn't know she is his daughter), and he tied her to a chair in a room (maybe a basement), she is confronted by her father and another man regarding her following him. He pulls up her history, finds out she is a gymnast, fencing expert etc in her school(?), basically she is super talented.
She describes herself as somewhat of a tomboy... eventually tells him she is his daughter... Later her beetle enters her driveway. 
That's all I remember about this episode (most likely) or movie, saw this on TV before 2013 and I don't think this a 90s show or movie, must be in the 2000s.. been racking my brain for a long time can't remember where I saw this... It felt like a comedy drama, I believe this is American.

TV movie: To Love and Die.
Synopsis:
There’s dysfunctional and then there’s darned near sociopathic and Hildy, focus of “To Love & Die,” is too close to the latter. It’s one thing to have deeply ingrained Daddy Issues that leave you bailing on relationships after three dates and leaving jobs just as quickly. It’s another when you discover that your long-lost dad (Tim Matheson) is a top-notch contract killer and suddenly everything in your life makes sense. Suddenly every detail writer Sara Goodman has provided for your character — including background aptitudes in fencing, archery, gymnastics, darts and paintball, plus gifts for stalking and evasive driving (albeit in a green VW bug, the least stealthy care imaginable)

Just curious Did you know of the movie or Did you search for it? Tyvm
